# Passing 0,1,2,...,N-1 as arguments to a function

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I have a function

```
template <typename T, typename... Args> void foo(const T&, Args...);
```

and I want to pass something like:

```
foo(vector, 0,1,2,3,..., vector.size() - 1);
```

where `vector` is a vector of some sort.  I can't use `std::make_index_sequence` because `vector.size()` is not a compile-time constant.  Is the above construction possible (e.g. using `std::iota` as a helper), without doing a linear search from 0 to infinity for what vector.size() equals to?

Comment: maybe I am completely misunderstanding the question (and I am almost sure i do ;), but what is the point of passing `vector,0,1,2,3...,vector.size()-1` when passing `vector` makes the same information available to that function?

Answer (score 6):

No.  Well, you could do a binary search or a lookup table, but that would still generate O(max size_t^2) code.

Few systems permit that much code to be generated and not die a horrible death: on a 64 bit computer, we are talking about on the order of 10^37 in function name length alone.  Storing all of those function names is practical if you place a copy of the current planet Earth around every star in the entire visible universe and use all of every one of those Earth's computer storage to just storing your list of function names.

You'll probably run into compiler limits before being able to do that, but I haven't tried icpc.

If you chose a smaller limit (say, a 1000), you could do it more practically.  With a relatively small upper bound, what I call a [magic switch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28225557/1774667) (that dispatches run-time values to compile-time constants) solves the problem.

Still, odds are the problem is with your plan.

Comment: _You'll **probably** run into compiler limits_. Love it. :-)